# Laravel, mysql query with join in model class

Tags: php, laravel-4

laravel creates its own model for each table. Since it is one of the most popular frame work, we gone for it. Most of our mysql queries are based on multiple tables, we use join and we write those queries in controller itself. Can some one tell us, how to handle queries with multiple tables in model class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define relation in your model class, For information regarding relationship see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

E.g. If I want to access State name, in my City page then:

> Controller:

```
$city = App::make('Platform\Storage\City\CityRepository')->view($city_id, false, [], ['state'=>array('id', 'name')])
```

> Repository:

```
public function view($id, $active=true, $fields=array(), $with=array()) {
        $query = $this->model->newQuery();
        $tableName = $this->model->getTable();

        if ($active) {
            $query->where($tableName . '.is_active', '=', 1);
        }
        if (!$fields) {
            $fields = array($tableName . '.*');
        }
        if ($with) {
            $with = $this->model->processWithSelects($with);
            $query->with($with);
        }

        try {
            return $query->with($with)->where($tableName . '.id', '=', $id)->first($fields);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new DBException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e->getPrevious());
        }
    }
```

> City Model:

```
public function state() {
    return $this->belongsTo('State');
}
```

For more info, visit these: [Tutorial on Repository](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/), [Laravel Query](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries), [Simple CRUD](http://culttt.com/2014/06/23/foundations-crud-laravel-4/)

> In your Controller, create a constructor:

```
public function __construct(Model $model) {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->model = $model; // Model $model, means IOC or Dependancy Injection
    }
```

Then do: `$this->model->function_in_your_model()`, to execute your model functions.

See, if that helps.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for your answer...     It will be much thankful, if u can explain, how to obtain query result in controller,where function is declared in model class and it uses relationships..